# ORA-28547 with php-fpm in docker container

Tags: php, oracle, docker, oci8, instantclient

I got a working php-fpm docker container acting as the php backend to a nginx frontend.  What I mean by working, is that it renders phpinfo output in the browser as expected.
My php-fpm container was produced by php-fpm-7.4 prod of the devilbox docker repo. It has OCI8 enable.

The issue:  I keep getting ORA-28547 when trying oci_connect

What I have done:

1--add /usr/lib/oracle/client64/lib  to a file inside ld.so.conf.d and run ldconfig -v
2--restart docker container.
3-- Now phpinfo shows ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/client64/lib

4--Add tnsnames.ora to /usr/lib/oracle/client6/lib/network/admin (there is a README.md file inside that folder that even tells you to do that)
5--Restart docker container again.
6-oci_connect still fails with the same error.

What I am missing?

Thank you very much for any pointers, I think I have browsed to the end of the internet and back without finding a solution yet.

----SOLUTION: reinstall instantclient, relink libraries (ldconfig) to use new instantclient libraries. Create modified dockerfile to do it when container is created.

I modified the Dockerfile file of the php-fpm to add new instant client files and not the one that were provided by the original file. I was not able to make it work with them. I have tried a few times rebuilding the image (docker-compose up --build) and this is the file that does the trick:

```
FROM devilbox/php-fpm:7.4-work

#instantclient.conf content: /opt/instantclient
RUN echo "/opt/instantclient" >/etc/ld.so.conf.d/instantclient.conf

WORKDIR /opt

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN mv instantclient_19_8 instantclient

ADD tnsnames.ora /opt/instantclient/network/admin

RUN ldconfig -v

CMD ["php-fpm"]

expose 9000
```

Comment: For reference, here are some Oracle references on Dockerfiles: [Instant Client 19c Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19) and [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check

https://github.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/blob/master/Dockerfile

which seems to create a p-fpm-oci8 docker image

the "wget" for

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf- -C /usr/local && 
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf-  -C /usr/local && 
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf- -C /usr/local && \

can be dropped when you place downloaded instant client files into local host dir

/usr/local

and extract them - resulting in

/usr/local/instantcient_12_2
or 18, 19c equivalents

the 4 "ln" commands have to be adjusted to reflect the local host instantclient dir

the tnsnames.ora for instantclient is available from host by VOLUME command

-------------FINAL SOLUTION------------(it was not network related, I had done a couple of changes to the files, and also tried a different database, all at the same time, so it made me think that it was the different database what fixed the issue)

After many trial and errors, I came up with a Dockerfile that creates the correct configuration of files and connects without any issues to the database:

--Dockerfile: (to build php-fpm 7.4 using devilbox image)

```
Final solution:
```

I modified the Dockerfile file of the php-fpm to add new instant client files and not the one that were provided by the original file. I was not able to make it work with them. I have tried a few times rebuilding the image (docker-compose up --build) and this is the file that does the trick:

FROM devilbox/php-fpm:7.4-work

ADD instantclient.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

WORKDIR /opt

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN mv instantclient_19_8 instantclient

ADD tnsnames.ora /opt/instantclient/network/admin

RUN ldconfig -v

CMD ["php-fpm"]

expose 9000

Comment: Hi @devnull Thank you for hanging around.     I did install my own copy of instantclient,  configure php-fpm (docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-instantclient=instantclient,<path>,  then make & then make install.             Then restart container.....error persists...........I did install the instantclient clients (sqlplus) and it works fine, connecting to the database with no issues.

Comment: After reading your link on the Dockerfie, I basically had done the same steps described in the Dockerfile.   One thing that I don't see is that in the output of phpinfo there is no mention to the --with-oci8=instantclient  that i have reinstall twice already (configure/make/make install)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Insert following to .bash_profile or .profile of the User starting the php-fpm
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
# Test to Ping Remote Db to be connected  by PHP 
tnsping <tns-name of remote DB - i.e. db12c.world>
 # restart here the php Engine
```

Comment: devnull,   I did it but it did not fix the issue. I don't have any client tool on this server yet (tnsping, sqlplus, etc).  This is a docker container, I see that php-fpm i s being ran by root (ps -ef), so I added it the env variables to its profile and bashrc scripts.  Thank you!

Comment: More info:  I went ahead and install the instantclient client tools. (sqlplus) and, I was able to use sqlplus to connect to one my databases described in tnsnames.ora.

Answer (score 0):

> I got it!.  It was a firewall issue.  I launched a tcpdump capture
> session and there was nothing wrong with php-fpm, oci8 and
> instantclient libraries.  The traffic was initiated but there was no
> response from the database. I made it work against a different
> database where this box has no firewall issues.
>
> I now will try rebuilding the docker image so I can see what I have to
> manually add if any.

That was incorrect (the firewall as the origin of the problem).  Rebuilding the docker file showed me where I had it wrong.  See original question for solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's why I have suggested to use tnsping - unfortunaly it is not included in any of the instant client files which is a pity - so you have to pick it up from regular client with matching OS, bitsize and Oracle release. As workaround you could place SQL*Plus package files into container and try to connect with a foo user like

```
sqlplus foo/foo@\<ip>:\<port>/\<dbname>
```

which should generate an error - if

- user/password not matching - ORA-1017 i.e. DB & listener running
- listener running - ORA-1034 i.e. DB down
- listener down (no return, or TNS-Errors)